# 'Financial' vs. 'economical'

Tags: word-choice, adjectives

Which of these is the right usage?

- John's *financial* situation is not good.
- John's *economic* situation is not good.

When is the usage of *financial* justified over *economic* and vice versa, given their similar meanings?

Comment: They mean different things. Please consult a dictionary before asking here.

Comment: The "al" endings seem like they should mean the same thing but they are completely unrelated

Comment: @Robusto (i) you are assuming that the OP hasn't consulted a dictionary, (ii) the dictionary is not always the best source for differentiating words with similar meanings, and (iii) most members to not have access to OED. OED defines *financial* and *economic*, respectively, as **Of, pertaining, or relating to finance or money matters.** and **Of or relating to household management, or to the ordering of private affairs; domestic.** Some further clarification is needed.

Comment: http://lexicon.ft.com/Term?term=finance http://lexicon.ft.com/Term?term=economy http://lexicon.ft.com/Term?term=economic

Answer (score 5):

"Economical" is the wrong word to use here.

> ec·o·nom·i·cal
>   /ˌekəˈnämikəl/
>   Adjective
>   Giving good value or service in relation to the amount of money, time, or effort spent.
>   (of a person or lifestyle) Careful not to waste money or resources.

You could say John's *economic* situation is not good, but that's a little ambiguous. *Financial* is a much better choice.

Comment: OP's erroneous *economical* has been edited out, but enlighten me - how is *John's economic situation* ambiguous? I can't see any difference between *economic/financial* in this context. Personally, I'd probably use *circumstances* rather than *situation*, but apparently I'm [in the minority there](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=his+economic+circumstances%2Chis+economic+situation%2Chis+financial+circumstances%2Chis+financial+situation&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=)

Comment: @FumbleFingers I mentioned "financial" as being a much better choice for reasons that jlovegren outlined well in his answer. As for ambiguity, I may be the one in the minority - but to my eyes "economic" could also mean his ability to be economical.

Comment: It's not so clear-cut for me with *electric/electrical*, but with *economic/economical*, I divide them pretty definitely as being connected to *finance/thrift* respectively. So I just wouldn't even register that ambiguity (OP's original erroneous usage stuck out like a sore thumb as implying "non-native speaker here!" :).

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, it's understandable to get confused on the usage of *economic* vs. *economical* (see [p.381 of Merriam-Webster's Dictionary of English usage](http://books.google.com/books?ei=7h_JUNXfFMOi2AXZ1oBQ&id=2yJusP0vrdgC&dq=merriam-webster%27s%20dictionary%20of%20english%20usage&jtp=300#v=onepage&q=economic&f=false) for explanation on the difference).

In current usage, *economic situation* is normally used in association with a large entity, especially a nation-state. It is rarely (but still occasionally) used with reference to specific individuals. *Financial situation*, on the other hand, is used in association with large entities, but also potentially with individuals, *e.g.,* John. *Financial situation* is then the preferred usage.

This assessment is in line with corpus data, some of which I give below. (*Caveat obtrectator*: corpus results are from a research-grade POS-tagged corpus which is sensitive to morphological boundaries.)

==========

Here are some hits for "economic situation" preceded by the genitive *'s* in [COCA](https://www.english-corpora.org) (notice that there are cases where the possessor is a family or an indefinite individual):

```
1        THESE DRIVERS ' ECONOMIC SITUATION MAY HAVE    1   
2        THEIR FAMILIES ' ECONOMIC SITUATION , MUST 1   
3        THE WORLD 'S ECONOMIC SITUATION FOR A  1   
4        THE TIBETANS ' ECONOMIC SITUATION DIRECTLY ,   1   
5        THE NATION 'S ECONOMIC SITUATION ON SEPT   1   
6        THE NATION 'S ECONOMIC SITUATION . ''  1   
7        THE NATION 'S ECONOMIC SITUATION , NOW 1   
8        THE LUMBEES ' ECONOMIC SITUATION GREW WORSE    1   
9        THE LEAGUE 'S ECONOMIC SITUATION : AT  1   
10       THE FAMILY 'S ECONOMIC SITUATION . ''  1   
11       THE COUNTRY 'S ECONOMIC SITUATION HAS WORSENED 1   
12       THAT TIBET 'S ECONOMIC SITUATION WOULD BE  1   
13       PARTICULAR EMPLOYEE 'S ECONOMIC SITUATION ; THE    1   
14       OF RUSSIA 'S ECONOMIC SITUATION IS A   1   
15       NORTH KOREA 'S ECONOMIC SITUATION DETERIORATES ,   1   
16       IN VIETNAM 'S ECONOMIC SITUATION , THE 1   
17       IN ONE 'S ECONOMIC SITUATION , ''  1   
18       IN AMERICA 'S ECONOMIC SITUATION WAS THE   1   
19       IMPROVED IRAN 'S ECONOMIC SITUATION AND HAVE   1   
20       IMPROVE SYRIA 'S ECONOMIC SITUATION AND BREAK  1   
21       IMPROVE ONE 'S ECONOMIC SITUATION . '' 1   
22       GIVEN PERU 'S ECONOMIC SITUATION , THE 1   
23       GIVEN G.M. 'S ECONOMIC SITUATION , ''  1   
24       BUT BATASHI 'S ECONOMIC SITUATION IS BETTER    1   
25       BALTIC REPUBLIC 'S ECONOMIC SITUATION .    1   
26       ABOUT JAPAN 'S ECONOMIC SITUATION AND HOW  1   
27       ABOUT CHRISTOPHER 'S ECONOMIC SITUATION BEFORE HE  1   
28       A COUNTRY 'S ECONOMIC SITUATION AND LIKELY 1   
29       A COUNTRY 'S ECONOMIC SITUATION .  1   
30       @@25365 TODAY 'S ECONOMIC SITUATION PRESENTS A
```

As for *financial situation,* the phrase still is applied to large entities such as corporations, and *state* and *nation*, it is however also applied with more frequency to individuals. Unlike the corpus hits for *economic situation*, we find the proper names referring to specific individuals.

```
1        DISCUSSED ENRON 'S FINANCIAL SITUATION . ''    2   
2        DENVER-BASED FRONTIER 'S FINANCIAL SITUATION HAS QUICKLY   1   
3        AT ERNIE 'S FINANCIAL SITUATION . AND  1   
4        AND SHANNON 'S FINANCIAL SITUATION MIGHT HAVE  1   
5        AND LOAN 'S FINANCIAL SITUATION WHO ARE    1   
6        ANALYZE INA 'S FINANCIAL SITUATION . MELMAN    1   
7        AC TRANSIT 'S FINANCIAL SITUATION ARE FAR  1   
8        A PERSON 'S FINANCIAL SITUATION . ''   1   
9         VINCENT 'S FINANCIAL SITUATION TELLS ONLY 1   
10       . JULIAN 'S FINANCIAL SITUATION CAUSED HIM 1   
11       . EVERYBODY 'S FINANCIAL SITUATION IS DIFFERENT    1   
12       , GORE 'S FINANCIAL SITUATION IS TIGHT 1   
13       , DAVID 'S FINANCIAL SITUATION . WAS   1   
14       , CARRUTH 'S FINANCIAL SITUATION WAS ANYTHING  1   
15       YOUR FAMILY 'S FINANCIAL SITUATION , YOU   1   
16       YOUR FAMILY 'S FINANCIAL SITUATION , LOCAL 1   
17       YOUR CHILD 'S FINANCIAL SITUATION AS WELL  1   
18       WOODY ALLEN 'S FINANCIAL SITUATION , BUT   1   
19       THIS COUNTRY 'S FINANCIAL SITUATION . LET  1   
20       THEIR PARENT 'S FINANCIAL SITUATION AS THEY    1   
21       THE TRIBE 'S FINANCIAL SITUATION . THE 1   
22       THE TEAM 'S FINANCIAL SITUATION HAS IMPROVED   1   
23       THE STATE 'S FINANCIAL SITUATION DETERIORATED ,    1   
24       THE STATE 'S FINANCIAL SITUATION AND EDUCATIONAL   1   
25       THE STATE 'S FINANCIAL SITUATION , HE  1   
26       THE ROCKIES ' FINANCIAL SITUATION DOES N'T 1   
27       THE ORGANIZATION 'S FINANCIAL SITUATION -- OPERATING   1   
28       THE MAGAZINE 'S FINANCIAL SITUATION . A    1   
29       THE LEAGUE 'S FINANCIAL SITUATION , ESPECIALLY 1   
30       THE INVESTOR 'S FINANCIAL SITUATION AND RISK
```

Comment: You're right that *financial* is favoured over *economic* for individuals, but ["personal economic **circumstances**"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22personal+economic+circumstances%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) isn't at all uncommon (although I'll admit "personal financial circumstances" is almost twice as common even there).

Answer (score -1):

You can talk about someone's finances but, you cannot talk about their economy, as economy is the flow of money between many entities, usually at country level.

Comment: People _do_ speak of household or personal economy—however, in the sense of frugal or prudent.

Comment: I don't see anything unusual in referring to ["my economic circumstances"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22my+economic+circumstances%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), nor do hundreds of others. And [thousands of people](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22his+economic+circumstances%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) have written about ***his** economic circumstances* (obviously they're less reticent talking about other people's money than their own! :) Just because *economy* doesn't fit so well doesn't rule out *economic* here.